# SCP Sync Support for Amazon EC2 on PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Is there anyway I can use PHPStorm to sync with my EC2 box through SCP?  EC2 requires a private key to connect to it.  I don't see any option for SCP in the deployment configuration section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SCP is file transfer over SSH, a newer version of which is SFTP. Both just work over SSH, if your server is accessible over SSH then these are the options you have. You're simply looking for the SFTP mechanism in PHPStorm with *Auth type* of "Key pair".

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for ES2 deployment integration, check [**Amazon EC2 plugin**](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1661?pr=). It is compatible with current latest version of PHPStorm. Аmong other features, it provide SSH client allowing connections to EC2 instances.

**Installation:**

Download latest plugin version.

In PHPStorm open **Settings** (by default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>). Then **Plugins** -> **Install plugin from disk**.

Answer (score 0):

there is a plugin called source sync https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7374?pr= it might help you. or you may use SCP.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with Phpstorm 3 without success but with the most recent version the ssh connection is working fine. 
I was able to have the ssh connexion with the version Webstorm 2018.3